# Rate limit dropping drastically

Tags: stocktwits

Hello I am noticing some strange behavior around request rates last night and this morning. I am doing a simple curl and my rate has gone from 68 -> 65 -> 61.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json
```

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with the large scale DDoS yesterday? I checked the announcement mailing list and I didn't see anything regarding this. When will this be back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate limit is based on the IP of the user. We were having some problems getting the correct IP from cloudflare's reverse proxy but this has been fixed.